# Can I export animated models from Unity? Into what formats?

Tags: unity, 3d, animation, models, export

I have an animated 3D model from the Unity Asset Store that I would like a new animator to touch up (the license allows this). But they need it in a format they can use (in Maya or... something else?). All I have been able to find so far is:

- how to export from the Editor into Unity Package format
- scripts to export the mesh (only?) into OBJ format [1]

Is it possible to export a textured and rigged model from Unity? If so, into what formats and how?

[1] [ObjExporter](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ObjExporter) and [ExportOBJ](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ExportOBJ)

Comment: What format was the asset provided in? Unity does not have a proprietary model format for assets, and converts models to FBX on import (pretty certain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity does not provide an export option for additional modelling. However, it does provide the option to [export an animated model (and other things)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html) into `.unitypackage` format using *Assets* > *Export package...*

(As far as I can tell this includes the [FBX files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) you can find in the project folder.)

In my case this was sufficient for the artist to inspect the model and animation visually in Unity, and the texture files directly. In the end, rather than adjusting the animation we used it as a reference.